# How to send notifications following recent Firestore updates using Firebase FCM and Ionic Native

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set up Cloud Messaging Functions using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOOjamH1bAA&t=317s

The code for my question is at 7:35 of this video. The full doc is in the link accessible from the video.

I am struggling with the recent updates to Firestore (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#cloud-firestore ), especially for time 7:35 of the youtube video link above. following the updates I changed the .onCreate to:

```
exports.newSubscriberNotification = functions.firestore   

.document('subscribers/{subscriberId}') 

.onCreate((snap,context) => {          //I notice no async event...

const data = snap.data();
```

The problem is: 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function. This makes sense as there is no longer an 'async event' due to the update.

`const devices = await devicesRef.get();`                 //see time 8:25 of video above.

If I add an async even above, the problem becomes: Property 'error' does not exist on type '“” | Promise' on the line:

`devices.forEach(result => {...})`                                //see time 8:35 of video above.

I have tried multiple solutions found online but I'm digging myself in a hole. I think the problem is I am not triggering the index.ts function file (according to console.log() ).

Please bear with me - I am relatively new to app development.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


admin.initializeApp();
console.log('before initializeApp');
exports.newSubscriberNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('subscribers/{subscriberId}') //odd
  .onCreate((snap,context) => {


      const data = snap.data();
      console.log('const data fired');

        const userId = data.userId
        const subscriber = data.subscriberId
        console.log('gathered data')

        // Notification content
        const payload = {
          notification: {
              title: 'New Subscriber',
              body: `${subscriber} is following your content!`,
          }
        }

        // ref to the device collection for the user
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const devicesRef = db.collection('devices').where('userId', '==', userId);


        // get the user's tokens and send notifications
        console.log('before await');
        const devices = await devicesRef.get();
        console.log('async function');

        console.log('before devices');
        //devices();
        console.log('after devices');
        const tokens = [];

        // send a notification to each device token

        devices.forEach(result => {
          const token = result.data().token;

          tokens.push( token )
        })

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)
  });
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show all the relevant code within the question itself without having to click through to a video.

Comment: Hi Doug, I have updated my post with the relevant code.

Comment: once I add the async function I get a typescript error:- Property 'forEach' does not exist on expression for devices.forEach(result => {...} . I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: What are you expecting `devices` to be?

Comment: An array of strings. It gets populated as a collection on the cloud Firestore. How would (should) I make that clear in the code?

Comment: If you dump `devices` to the log, is it exactly what you expect?

Comment: undefined, is it for the reason above?

Comment: Seems to me you have to figure out why you're getting undefined instead of whatever it is you expect.

Comment: I figure from your response that it was the right thing to add the async function - I couldn't tell if that was right in the first place. I figure I'm on the right track then - thanks I guess

Comment: It's neither right nor wrong to use async/await.  It's a matter of programming style.

Comment: Hey buddy! im trying to do something like you, but im getting a crash: ERROR in node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/function-configuration.d.ts(4,64): error TS1005: ']' expected. can you help me please? its because im importing like you the firebase-functions but doesnt work...